# Can I start a sound with a command?

Tags: command-line, audio-player

I want to know if there is a command that starts playing a sound, then moves on with the rest of the script. I need this because I want to play a sound WHILE other scripts are running, and most tools that play sound wait for the sound to be completed before moving on.

Comment: That is equivalent to a command that plays a sound and ends. Moving on to the rest of the script would be a shell default behavior.

Comment: May be helpful: [How do I make my pc speaker beep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1974)

Comment: What kind of sound do you want to play? Is it stored in a file, in that case what kind of file?

Answer (score 3):

`paplay`

from `man paplay`[1](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/man1/paplay.1.html)

> pacat - Play back or record raw or encoded audio streams on a PulseAudio sound server

the tool I'm referring to is `paplay` (or pulse audio play)

eg.

```
paplay /usr/share/sounds/KDE-Sys-App-Error-Critical.ogg
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 22.04 and newer install use PipeWire, replacing the older PulseAudio.

In PipeWire systems, use the `pw-play` command.

Example:

```
pw-play /usr/share/sounds/KDE-Sys-App-Error-Critical.ogg
```